# Failed an interview due to unit test - I need to learn why

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, fluent-assertions

I went for an interview and was given a NUnit test, which failed and asked why it failed, and I couldnt find a reason. During debug the values were all the same except the ID, which was 1 and 0 respectively.

I am not strong in testing, but want to learn my mistake, what do I look out for and why did it fail ?

I ran it in debug mode and got the first error, but dont see what the problem is.  WHATS WRONG WITH THIS UNIT TEST. I was asked to fix it, but within the alloted time I couldnt find the reason for failure

ERROR MESSAGE

```
NUnit.Framework.AssertionException


HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Expected _context.Account {Root.CLIENTBooking.Data.Models.Account
   {
      Created = <2021-08-31 07:58:18.8245439>
      DateOfBirth = <2021-10-26 02:51:07.9281209>
      Email = "Email44cc0cbb-a6c3-43a5-974d-e1003b958854"
      FirstName = "FirstNameda3ad7fd-f2d4-4720-92df-46f82b6406cd"
      Gender = 0
      Id = 1L
      LastName = "LastName765872d6-7fe9-475a-b217-87c45ca7e1a6"
      Orders = {empty}
   }} to contain equivalent of 

Root.CLIENTBooking.Data.Models.Account
{
   Created = <2021-08-31 07:58:04.4695485>
   DateOfBirth = <2021-10-26 02:51:07.9281209>
   Email = "Email44cc0cbb-a6c3-43a5-974d-e1003b958854"
   FirstName = "FirstNameda3ad7fd-f2d4-4720-92df-46f82b6406cd"
   Gender = 0
   Id = 0L
   LastName = "LastName765872d6-7fe9-475a-b217-87c45ca7e1a6"
   Orders = {empty}
}.

With configuration:
- Use declared types and members
- Compare enums by value
- Exclude member root.Id
- Match member by name (or throw)
- Without automatic conversion.
- Be strict about the order of items in byte arrays

  Source=FluentAssertions
  StackTrace:
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.LateBoundTestFramework.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.TestFrameworkProvider.Throw(String message)
   at FluentAssertions.Execution.CollectingAssertionStrategy.ThrowIfAny(IDictionary`2 context)
   at FluentAssertions.Collections.CollectionAssertions`2.ContainEquivalentOf[TExpectation](TExpectation expectation, Func`2 config, String because, Object[] becauseArgs)
   at Root.CLIENTBooking.Service.Tests.AccountServices.AccountServiceTests.AddAccount_AddsAccountToContextWithGeneratedId() in C:\Users\XXXXXoz\OneDrive\Documents\XXXXX TEst\Root.CLIENTBooking.Service.Tests\AccountServices\AccountServiceTests.cs:line 110
```

Test

```
  [Test]
    public void AddAccount_AddsAccountToContextWithGeneratedId()
    {
        //arrange
        var request = _fixture.Create<AddAccountRequest>();

        var expected = new Account
        {
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            DateOfBirth = request.DateOfBirth,
            Gender = (int)request.Gender,
            Email = request.Email,
            Orders = new List<Order>(),
            Created = DateTime.UtcNow
        };

        //act
        _AccountService.AddAccount(request);

        //assert
        _context.Account.Should().ContainEquivalentOf(expected, options => options.Excluding(Account => Account.Id));
    }
```

ACCOUNT CLASS

```
    public class Account
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Gender { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

ADD ACCOUNT CLASS

```
public class AddAccountRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

FINALLY

ACCOUNT SERVICE

```
  public void AddAccount(AddAccountRequest request)
    {
        var validationResult = _validator.ValidateRequest(request);

        if (!validationResult.PassedValidation)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(validationResult.Errors.First());
        }

        _context.Account.Add(new Account
        {
            FirstName = request.FirstName,
            LastName = request.LastName,
            DateOfBirth = request.DateOfBirth,
            Gender = (int)request.Gender,
            Email = request.Email,      
            Orders = new List<Order>(),
            Created = DateTime.UtcNow
        });

        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the `Created` time is different, both values are set at different times and are therefore not equal.